# iOS App Beta Tester getting in-app purchase sandbox

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, sandbox, storekit

I have in-app purchases in my app, which are live on the app store. I have sent out a new beta to my testers, and one is trying to make an in-app purchase but it is coming up with the sandbox. Is this supposed to happen? They do not have a testing account and actually want to spend money, so I figured I should ask: How or why do beta testers, who are running my iOS app on their phones and not the iOS simulator, get the app store's sandbox as opposed to the regular app store?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your tester will signout from testing account from Setting & they are using proper iTunes account for purchasing the product. I assume you have used proper product identifier in code as you have entered in IAP of live application. It would be great if you can once check IAP of your application in iTunes with that in code.